# Disable or lock text edit PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to disable a text edit (when a button is clicked), so the user can no longer be able to add text in there.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 11):

You can set it as read-only with:

```
self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
```

I prefer this to the `setDisabled` method because it maintains its original visual appearance.

Answer (score 8):

Use this to disable text edit ([QTextEdit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html)) in PyQt

```
self.textEdit.setDisabled(True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the text edit object's [setDisabled()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setDisabled) function

Comment: Thank you, I've looked in the official documentation http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html but I didn't find a method like this.

Comment: The documentation only shows new method implementations for a given class. You also have access to any non-private methods inherited from parent classes. The setDisabled function is inherited from QWidget.